# 19.10: After installing NVIDIA drivers my user interface is not smooth

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

Does anyone know why after I install NVIDIA drivers, my user interface experience is downgraded. For example when I move opened window around the screen rendering is very bad, it’s not smooth.

I have an NVIDIA 960m in a Lenovo y700, running Ubuntu 19.10.

I have tried installing all NVIDIA drivers from 340 to 440 but all of them doesn’t work well. I have tried the same things on Ubuntu 18.04 but it didn’t work.

After running: lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

```
arturas@arturas-ubuntu:-$ 1spci -k I grep -EA3 'VGA| 3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 530
Kernel driver in use: 1915
Kernel modules: i915
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Lenovo GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nvidlafb, nouveau
arturas@arturas-ubuntu:-$
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Updated my question, and wanted to ask you what is virtualization?

Comment: If you don't know, you ain't using it  See https://opensource.com/resources/virtualization and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization  Also, 18.10 is not supported; it reached its end of life in April 2019. 18.04 is the Long Term Support alternative.

Comment: Have you tried to install the proprietary driver from NVIDIA?

Comment: Yes I have, on both versions of Ubuntu

Comment: You are supposed to install the correct proprietary driver by running the following commands: `sudo apt update` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`